# how to display value from json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i have json array like following

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "abx",
    },{
        id:2,
        name: "silver"
    }
];
```

is this possible in angularjs. i can display name of json according to assign value like

```
var x = 2;

{{data.x.name}}
```

i mean if have id of row is 2 then i just want to show `{{name}}` directly not want to add looping code and match `id == record.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly in dot notation? No. You can write a method that takes an id, then returns the name from that:

```
$scope.getNameFromId(data, id) {
    var item = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id === id
    });

    return item.length ? item[0].name : "N/A";
}
```

Then in your view:

```
{{getNameFromId(data, 2)}}
```